# Matrix Notation for Linear Solvers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

I am reading up on linear solvers, and I keep seeing notation that I am unsure on.

$$\alpha_j = \frac{(r_j, z_j)}{(AP_j, p_j)}$$

Does the notation $(r_j, z_j)$ mean the Euclidean distance between $r_j$ and $z_j$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it means $\langle r_j, z_j \rangle$ which is the inner product.

Typically we have
$$\langle r_j,z_j \rangle = r_j^*z_j$$

Comment: See updated question, I made a mistake typing in the question.